# copy, drag & drop bug : item stops moving

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to drag and drop items on a page, but insteads of moving the item itself, I create a copy of it.

Here is my code. "copyDragDrop" is a div at the bottom of the page. It remains empty until the user strats dragging something.

```
function coordSouris()
{
 return {
  x:event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,
  y:event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  - document.body.clientTop
    };
}

function drag()
{
    var pos = coordSouris(event);
    copie = event.srcElement.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('copieDragDrop').appendChild(copie);
    copie.style.position = 'absolute';
    copie.style.display = 'block';

    document.onmousemove = mouseMove;
    document.onmouseup = drop;
}


function mouseMove()
{
    if (copie != null)
    {
        var pos = coordSouris(event);
        copie.style.left = pos.x;
        copie.style.top = pos.y;
    }
}

function drop()
{
    var divCopie = document.getElementById('copieDragDrop');
    if (divCopie.hasChildNodes() )
    {
        while ( divCopie.childNodes.length >= 1 )
        {
            divCopie.removeChild(divCopie.firstChild);       
        } 
    }
}
```

This code creates the copy, starts to move it, but after a few pixels, the copy stops following the mouse. If I release the mouse, "onmouseup" is not fired, but the copy starts to follow the mouse again ! I've tried the code on several items, the same bug occurs

I don't understand anything, any help is more than welcome.

**UPDATE :** I juste realised that all elements I tried the code on had something in common : they contained or were included in an ASP.net hyperlink control. The same code works well on regular HTML elements. There must be some auto-generated javascript for links that interferes with my code.

Comment: To make sure all your functions are loaded and ready before you call them, check to make sure they're in the head of your html. Sounds trivial, but I ran into these problems before.

Comment: I moved the script to the head and it didn't change anything. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. By the way, you should put anything that does not need to be displayed (JS code, hidden fields, unvisible divs...) at the end of the body tag, if possible. This way it will not delay the display of visible content and your page will seem to load faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find the auto-generated code responsible for the issue, so I simply solvec this by replacing Hyperlink controls by standard HTML anchors.